# Gradle Copy Task: How to overwrite existing files?

Tags: java, copy, gradle, overwrite

The [Copy](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) api doesn't mention a flag/property that can be set. So what's the default action and how can one modify it?

---

According to [this](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1264),

> As of Gradle 0.9.1, the Copy task always overwrites files. The other
>   strategies are not supported yet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As the issue text says, the `Copy` task overwrites files, and other strategies aren't currently supported. If that's not appropriate in your case, you can always fall back to the Ant task.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to hear it straight from the horses mouth! :D Any idea when those new strategies will be implemented (if at all)?

Comment: What's the situation now?

Answer (score 5):

Check out DuplicatesStrategy http://www.gradle.org/docs/1.7-rc-1/release-notes#duplicate-file-handling-for-copy-and-archive-operations and http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/DuplicatesStrategy.html. Both should work for non-overwrite copying (while overwrite-copying is default).

```
duplicatesStrategy 'exclude'
```

Also check out [Gradle Zip DuplicatesStrategy not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26036879/gradle-zip-duplicatestrategy-not-working-correctly) for a possible bug that exists with nested "from"s.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem when i use the Task Copy, gradle always performs up-to-date check which causes copying be skipped.

After read more on the gradle user manual, i find out that we can use project.copy() method instead of the task **Copy**. This method skip the up-to-date check, thus files will be always be copyed to destination.

```
task myCopy << {
    copy {
        from (yourSourceDir)
        into (yourDestDir)
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like trying to fix a problem that you created yourself (due to the `<<`). Look at the accepted answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358194/force-task-execution-in-gradle