# Force task execution in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

A certain amount of Gradle tasks I wrote, don't need any in- or output. Because of that, these tasks always get the status `UP-TO-DATE` when I call them. An example:

```
task backupFile(type: Copy) << {
    //Both parameters are read from the gradle.properties file
    from file(adjusting_file.replaceAll("\"", "")) 
    into file(backupDestinationDirectory + "/main/")

    println "[INFO] Main file backed up"
}
```

Which results in the following output:

```
:gradle backupFile
:backupFile UP-TO-DATE
```

---

Is there a way to **force a(ny) task to execute, regardless of anything**? 
If there is, is it also possible to **toggle task execution** (e.g. telling the build script which tasks to run and which tasks to ignore)?

I can't omit the `<<` tags, as that would make the tasks to *always* execute, which isn't what I desire.

Many thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: _I can't omit the << tags, as that would make the tasks to always execute_
 => This is not correct, I bet you say that because your println statement shows everytime your invoke gradle on your build file. Long story short, the `>>` is used to define an **action** for your task, hence the println would be part of this action and show only when the task is executed. Without the `>>` you define a task **configuration** hence your println will show each and every times, but it does not mean the task has been executed, but only it has been _configured_.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tasks have to be configured in the *configuration phase*. However, you are configuring it in a task action (`<< { ... }`), which runs in the *execution phase*. Because you are configuring the task too late, Gradle determines that it has nothing to do and prints `UP-TO-DATE`.

Below is a correct solution. Again, I recommend to use `doLast` instead of `<<` because it leads to a more regular syntax and is less likely added/omitted accidentally.

```
task backupFile(type: Copy) {
    from file(adjusting_file.replaceAll("\"", "")) 
    into file(backupDestinationDirectory + "/main/")
    doLast {
        println "[INFO] Main file backed up"
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that make the task just *always* execute?

Comment: No it does not. I recommend to step back a bit, study the first few chapters of the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html), and experiment with the samples in the full Gradle distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to do this for many days.
I have to create many intermidate jars on the processResource step. 
Following one needs to be created  on the processResource step.

```
processResources.dependsOn(packageOxygenApplet)  //doesn't work

task packageOxygenApplet (type: Jar) {

    println '** Generating JAR..: ' + rsuiteOxygenAppletJarName
        from(sourceSets.main.output) {
            include "org/worldbank/rsuite/oxygen/**"
        }
        baseName = rsuiteOxygenAppletJarName

        manifest {
            attributes("Build-By": oxygenUsername,
                "Specification-Title": "Oxygen World Bank Plugin")
        }
        destinationDir = file("src/main/resources/WebContent/oxygen")

}
```