# Gradle Zip DuplicatesStrategy not working correctly

Tags: gradle, zip, duplicates

Suppose you have something like:

```
task zip(type: Zip) {
  archiveName = "out.zip"
  duplicatesStrategy = 'exclude'

  into('TARGET_FOLDER_IN_ZIP') {
    from("$rootDir/customizations/folder1")
    from("$rootDir/customizations/folder2")
  }
}
```

According to http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/DuplicatesStrategy.html Exclude means

> Do not allow duplicates by ignoring subsequent items to be created at the same path.

So if you have the same filename in folder1 & folder2 only the file from folder1 should end up in the zip. If you change the two "from" lines in the buildfile, only the file from folder2 should end up there. This seems not to be whats happening (gradle 1.10). Instead always the same file is used. Seems like nested "from"s do not preserve their order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I've found is to split up the conflicting parts:

```
  into('TARGET_FOLDER_IN_ZIP') {
    from("$rootDir/customizations/folder1")
  }
  into('TARGET_FOLDER_IN_ZIP') {
    from("$rootDir/customizations/folder2")
  }
```

now the order is preserved and the output is deterministic